# Server unreachable from one interface

Tags: networking, server, interface

I have an ubuntu server and a windows server both connected in two VLANs.

Both machines have two NICs.

- VLAN2 has scheme 192.168.2.0 /24
- VLAN100 has 172.20.100.64 /27.

I am able to ping the windows server VLAN100 address from the VLAN2 network but I cannot ping the ubuntu server VLAN100 address.

I have to be in VLAN100 to reach the ubuntu server.

**How can I go about resolving this issue?**
[image: Network snippet]

my /etc/network/interfaces file config:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

#source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback



auto eno1
    iface eno1 inet static
    address 192.168.2.252
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.2.1

auto eno2
    iface eno2 inet static
    address 172.20.100.65
    netmask 255.255.255.224
```

Comment: Do you have [ip forwarding](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-turn-on-off-ip-forwarding-in-linux) enabled on the Ubuntu Server?

Comment: turning it on or off doesnt make a difference. there is a router on the network to route between the networks @derHugo

Comment: `Both machines have two NICs. ` made me somehow think they are both connected to both Networks and therefor there would be no router between them ... Maybe me you should add an image of your Network structure to your question

Comment: @derHugo 2NICs because one network is for DMZ to access the machines web servers from the internet